# Single Application for Both Online and Offline

Tags: java, html, oracle-adf

We are working for a client wherein we have developed custom ADF application which is used by online users(Web Users - Who are connected to internet).  All the Data used for this Application is stored in Data base.

We have similar offline Desktop(Standalone) Application , built on Java Swings which is used by the users when they are not connected to internet(Offline Mode). Here the input and output data is stored in XML files.

Now client wants to eliminate the Standalone desktop application. They want one single Application(Single Code base) which should work both as online when connected to internet and should work as offline when not connected to internet.

Can we achieve this using HTML5?. If Yes, please share the IDE and other technology links.

If not, Please gives us pointer on what are the java technologies avialable in the market to acheive the same ?

Please note that our current ADF application is integrated with Oracle EBS.

Comment: [Offline](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/offline) web apps (available in HTML5) might be a good place to start.

Comment: Will that application(Same code) works both offline and online ?

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible, but your javascript will play a great role with help of @Mike W link in which you will need to save this data in your html application cache using javascript and check for online status and start transfer this data back to Database.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working on a package for financial advisers, this has  the same access constraints: Web access if there's a live internet connection, or a standalone application if there isn't (at a client site for example).

In this instance we've chosen to go with javafx.  The app can be deployed/built as standalone or for access via a browser.  It's relatively easy to create both from the same code base.

The XML/DB access could be based on your current code (we use sqlite with but that's irrelevant for your solution).

Not sure how ADF plays with javafx though.